# Joomla T3 placing Javascript as module in the menu

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, module

I have a  question, I have tried  to put some JavaScript on the T3 menu as a module. However, there are some problems because I soon  as I touch the area the content disappears. Does anyone know if there a module that holds all the content without having any conflicts please.

Comment: It might be an idea to show your JS code ;)

Comment: I have used some examples from online, will put some code later is just a general question to see if the mega menu supports java-script in a container when placing custome modules.